# Why is Gimp engaging keyboard shortcuts when I export and save?

Tags: mac, gimp

I'm using Gimp 2.8 on Mac Mavericks. Not sure what I did (this was not a problem before). Suddenly when I export or save, if I use a shortcut letter in the file name, it engages the shortcut and won't allow that letter in the name. It's bizarre! For example I export an image, the file save dialog appears if I type s the select tool is chosen instead of adding s to the file name. Anyone know how to stop this madness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue, but good news,the problem was fixed in GIMP 2.8.10, so if you're running into this problem please download the newer version.